# Self increment primary key in Oracle NoSQL Database

Tags: oracle-nosql

I have the following, how do I make the id (primary key) self incremented from the db point of view? Thank you.

I feel that, if there are several different threads(or sessions) access below userTable at the same time, it will be a little bit tricky to maintain the id by myself.

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists userTable
(
    userid integer,
    loginname string,
    mobilephone string,
    workemail string,
    primary key (userid)
);
```

What is the best way to model this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a primary key field as an IDENTITY column and the system will allocate and increment that field for you on insert.

See: More information here
[https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/20.2/java-driver-table/defining-tables-identity-colum…](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/20.2/java-driver-table/defining-tables-identity-colum%E2%80%A6)